# grub rescue (all partitions) : unknown filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, grub, rescue

I am stuck with grub rescue.

I have a dual-boot with a Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04. Now when I try to boot my laptop, it enters grub rescue mode.

I tried `ls` commond:

```
grub rescue > ls
```

The results are as followed:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

Then I tried:

```
grub rescue > ls (hd0)/
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos6)/
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos5)/
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos2)/
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos1)/
```

and

```
grub rescue > ls (hd0)/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos6)/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos5)/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos2)/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos1)/grub
```

and

```
grub rescue > ls (hd0)/boot/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos2)/boot/grub
grub rescue > ls (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
```

All these commands returned with a result:

```
error: unknown filesystem
```

No linux partitions were found? What should I do?

Comment: Simplest usually is to boot from a live medium and repair from there.